# School Quality Data at the County Level

Tags: data-request, usa, education

Is anyone familiar with data that that has or could give provide a measure of school quality at the county level?

Answer (score 1):

The Department of Education maintains rating data on schools in a large number of categories. You can build your own tables here:

http://eddataexpress.ed.gov/state-tables-main.cfm

The US Dept. of Ed also has related search tools here:

http://nces.ed.gov/datatools/

The link below will allow you to very a variety of aggregated data at state, county, school district and school level. Note, only a minimal amount of data is aggregated at county level.

http://nces.ed.gov/ccd/elsi/expressTables.aspx

For those that want to fully customize their results (datasets), use this tool:

http://nces.ed.gov/ccd/elsi/tableGenerator.aspx

Comment: Everything that I've seen on those sites is at the state level. Did you have something in mind when you suggested them for finding county level data?

Comment: @timothy.s.lau - I updated my answer.

Comment: Using the table generator I was only able to get county demographics, not achievement. Did you have something in mind related to achievement when suggesting this option?

Comment: I recheck the table and express generators. They are limited to demographic and financial data. But they do have FTE counts, expenditure per student, etc. The USEd has a lot of survey data. You may have to hand find what you are looking for from their catalog: http://nces.ed.gov/surveys/SurveyGroups.asp?Group=1